# How can I link against glut32 in cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin, glut

I am trying to run [someone else's (4 year old) code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autodistrict/) from sourceforge. I downloaded cygwin and checked out the project with CVS.

Here is the [compile](http://autodistrict.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/autodistrict/bmp_version/compile_dir/compile?view=markup) line which is failing:

```
gcc ../block_display/block_display.c -o block_display -lopengl32 -lglut32 -lm
```

Here is the relevant include statement in [block_display.c](http://autodistrict.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/autodistrict/bmp_version/block_display/block_display.c?view=markup):

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

When I try to run the above compile line, I get this compile error:

```
$ gcc ../block_display/block_display.c -o block_display -lopengl32 -lglut32 -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut32
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I admit I am new/rusty with cygwin. I tried a few things to get to this point, but since I don't entirely know where to put files, I am stuck on this error. Here is what I have tried:

1. Downloading all results for 'glut' in cygwin setup: libglut-devel, freeglut, libglut3
2. Downloading [glut 3.7.6](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut/glut-3.7.6-bin.zip), copying glut32.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64, and copying glut.h to C:\cygwin\usr\include. I still have glut.def and glut32.lib sitting around, but I do not know exactly where to place them. I tried following [this install guide](http://www.cs.csustan.edu/~rsc/SDSU/GLUTinstall.html), but since I am not running VC++, I do not know what the cygwin equivalent of VC++ path is.

Any idea what I could do to get this code to compile successfully? I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) instead. The original glut is far outdated. Freeglut on the other hand is binary and source compatible with the original glut, and it's also open source.

Since glut32.dll is a windows DLL and cygwin is for emulating a unix environment on windows, you can't easily use the original glut with cygwin without recompiling from source.

Comment: This is not my code so my preference would be to make no changes to it since I am trying to verify that it is working code as it currently exists. What changes would I need to make the code to use freeglut? Does it have the same API as glut? Do I need to use a different -l argument? Do I need to change the include statement?

Comment: freeglut was designed to be a drop in replacement for glut, so you shouldn't have to change any code.

Comment: I changed the compile line to this and everything worked as you said: gcc ../block_display/block_display.c -o block_display -lopengl32 -lGL -lglut -lm